# NuKeeper - how to add reviewers for pull request?

Tags: azure, yaml, nuget, devops, pipeline

I am currently using Nukeeper in my Azure DevOps pipeline to automatically update my packages. It works fine and automatically creates a Pull Request when the pipeline is run. However, the Pull Requests do not have any required/optional reviewers assigned. I would like to automatically assign **Optional Reviewers** with Specific names to the PR.

I have looked into the Nukeeper configurations at https://nukeeper.com/basics/configuration/ but could not find any options to achieve the above.

Below is my Yaml content:

```
trigger: none
schedules:
- cron: "0 3 * * 0"
  displayName: Weekly Sunday update
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

pool: CICDBuildPool-VS2019

steps:
- task: NuKeeper@0
  displayName: NuKeeper Updates
  inputs:
    arguments: --change Minor --branchnameprefix "NewUpdates/" --consolidate
```

Does anyone know if it is feasible to automatically assign specific optional reviewers via the Nukeeper pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

This Can be done through branch policy "Automatically included reviewers" option.